# Spring bean decoration without ambiguity errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, decorator

I have the following scenario: A factory interface with 2 implementations, while the second one used as decorator to the first one.

```
public final class BaseMailFactory implements MailFactory {

    @Autowired
    private final ClassA classA;

    @Autowired
    private final ClassB classB;

    public Mail createMail(){
        .
        .
        .
    }
}

public final class MetricAwareMailFactory implements MailFactory {

    private final MailFactory mailFactory;

    public Mail createMail(){
        var mail = mailFactory.createMail();
        return new MetricsAwareMail(mail);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MailFactoryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MailFactory metricsAwareMailFactory(){
        return new MetricAwareMailFactory(???);
    }
}
```

The wrapped object previously instantiated through spring container (context), hence all auto wired fields populated successfully. After creation of the second implementation I am struggle to find an elegant way to initialize the first instance without adding multiple implementations to `MailFactory` interface which leads to application startup errors due to ambiguity.

I know that I can use qualifies for that but they pollute my code.

I am looking for a way to instantiate a class through spring but without actually register it as a bean, in older spring versions I get to use anonymous beans for such purposes.

Comment: So you do not want your `BaseMailFactory` to be a bean but still you use `@Autowired` annotations there? This will not work.

Comment: I do want that it will be initialized as bean but not registered with bean registry.

Answer (score -1):

I found the `@Primary` annotation useful here:

```
@Configuration
public class MailFactoryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    MailFactory baseMailFactory(){
        return new BaseMailFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MailFactory metricsAwareMailFactory(){
        return new MetricAwareMailFactory(baseMailFactory());
    }
}
```

I such way, both beans will be created but the primary one will be selected in case of multiple implementations.